# Consultar filas SQL devuelve el valor a string

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

Necesito hacer una consulta en mi servidor SQL y que me devuelva el numero de Filas (Usuarios Registrados) y ponerlos en un string o textBox.
WinForm C#.

Llamada

```
private ContadorLogins RRRRR = new ContadorLogins();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = RRRRR.Prueba();
}
```

Clase

```
private MySqlDataReader leer;
private String Mensaje;
private ConexionR Conexion = new ConexionR();
String DATOS;

public String Prueba()
{
    try
    {
        Comando.Connection = Conexion.AbrirConexion();
        Comando.CommandText = "Select count(*) from Usuarios";
        Comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        leer = Comando.ExecuteReader();
        if (leer.Read() == true)
        {
            DATOS = leer.ToString();
            Mensaje = string.Format(DATOS);
            leer.Close();
            Comando.Connection = Conexion.CerrarConexion();
        }
        else
        {
            leer.Close();
            Comando.Connection = Conexion.CerrarConexion();
        }
    }
    catch{}
    return Mensaje;
}
```

He buscado por aquí y por internet y no he conseguido una solución.

No me devuelve el valor de las filas.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tú problema exactamente?

Comment: No me devueve valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que voy aconsejar es que quites esto

```
catch{}
```

NUNCA se define un catch vacio, porque si hay un error nunca te enteras, al menos debes loguear en un archivo el problema

Despues usa el `ExecuteScalar()` para obtener un valor simple

```
public int Prueba()
{
    var Connection = Conexion.AbrirConexion();

    string query = "Select count(*) from Usuarios";
    SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand(query, Connection);

    int cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(Comando.ExecuteScalar());

    return cantidad;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo adapte un poco y me funcionó.
`public int Prueba()
        {
            Comando.Connection = Conexion.AbrirConexion();
            Comando.CommandText = "Select count(*) from Usuarios";
            int cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(Comando.ExecuteScalar());
            return cantidad;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar

```
leer = Comando.ExecuteReader();
if (leer.Read() == true)
{
 DATOS = leer.ToString();
 Mensaje = string.Format(DATOS);
 leer.Close();
 Comando.Connection = Conexion.CerrarConexion();
}

DATOS = leer.ToString();
Mensaje = string.Format(DATOS);
```

por

```
int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();    
leer.Close();
Comando.Connection = Conexion.CerrarConexion();
Mensaje = count.ToString();
```

Comment: Hola Fran, gracias por la ayuda, he puesto lo que me dices, pero me salta este error:

Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Comment: Te he editado la respuesta, prueba ahora

Comment: E probado en: 
`....
                leer = Comando.ExecuteReader();
                if (leer.Read() == true)
                {
                    DATOS = leer.ToString();
                    Mensaje = string.Format(DATOS);
                    leer.Close();
                    Comando.Connection = Conexion.CerrarConexion();
                }
            return Mensaje;
        ` En el textBox me pone lo siguiente: **MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader**

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, solo debes cambiar una linea en tu codigo:

```
DATOS = leer.ToString();
```

por

```
DATOS = leer[0].ToString();
```

Ya que no le estas diciendo que datos quieres obtener de la consulta

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.